# Xamarin Forms Post Request Body

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
public async static Task<RootUserData> getUSerLoggedIn(string userName, string password)
    {
        RootUserData rootUserData = new RootUserData();
        var url = URlConstants.LOGIN_URL;
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =  new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{userName}:{password}");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("content-type", "application/json");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("cache-control", "no-cache");




        } ;
    }
```

I am using above code to make one Service call. I have to pass userEmailAddress in body as plain as shown in Postman Picture. Can You Please help me How to achieve this?

[image: Please see this Picture]

Comment: Are you trying to send the username as `application/json`? Or ....

Comment: No... Its in Plain Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No... Its in Plain Text

Set your content mime type to "text/plain":

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("content-type", "text/plain");
```

And post a string:

```
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(userName));
```

Comment: Thanks For the answer... httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("content-type", "text/plain"); .. this Line was giving error. It worked after I commented it...

Answer (score 0):

Content-Type should not be added like that, It didn't work in my case, and gave a wrong response, instead

Pass content-Type like this -

```
httpRequest.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```